# No back button with Push Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have 2 view controllers A and B, when a UIButton is tapped on A, I have a push segue that goes to B, on A I have this in viewDidLoad

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

And then in B I have this in viewDidLoad

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
```

But in B, I see no back button what is going on? Why does this happen?

If I do the swipe fully across the screen it will go back, but I want the back button in the nav bar.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why are you adding self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton in A & B?

Comment: @Gagan_iOS because I want it hidden in A, but not in B

Answer (score 0):

Actually it hides the navigation bar button in complete stack when you hide it in `parentView`. To hide navigation `barButton`, write your code in `viewWillAppear` of A `viewController`

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

And in A `viewController`'s `viewWillDisappear`, unhide the navigation button

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
}
```

Now it will show up the navigation bar button in B `viewController`.

**Update**

Instead of hiding `backButton` on A `viewController`, set `backButton` nil

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

And add custom `backButton` on B `viewController`

Comment: When I go from A to B, I see it for a split second and then it disappears, but then if i got from A to B a second time the back button stays? That seems weird to me

Comment: actually I only see the back button every even number I go to B, so the 1st, its not there, the 2nd its there, the 3rd not there, 4th its there and so on?

Comment: Do you need `backButton` on A viewController ?

Comment: view controller A has no `backButton`